# variable does not exist in sas data set

Tags: grep, sas, cat

I am trying to check whether variable `GROUP` exist in SAS data set file or not from the UNIX command but unfortunately it's showing that `GROUP` variable does not exist in the data set,However `GROUP` variable is present in SAS data set.

In my command for case sensitive and whole word match I am using `i` and `w` options of grep command respectively. But still UNIX command is not giving the expected result.I s there any way to fix this issue?

Below is the command which I am using:

```
sasfile="sasdata"
rwords="GROUP"

cat $sasfile | grep -iqw "$rwords"
```

Thank you

Comment: SAS **data sets** are stored in disk files using a **proprietary** format.  There may be encodings and storage methodologies that do not yield the information you seek in a plain text examination of grep determined words.

Comment: Did you try grepping the output from `strings` ? `strings $sasdataset | grep -i GROUP`

Comment: Hi Richard, Yes, I am keeping the SAS data set variable names in string and then searching the those strings (SAS variables) in SAS data set from UNIX command.

Comment: Please update your question showing the output from the unix command `strings $sasfile`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in earlier comment

> SAS data sets are stored in disk files using a proprietary format.
>   There may be encodings and storage methodologies that do not yield the
>   information you seek in a plain text examination of said disk file.

Running SAS code in a SAS session is the definitive way to glean information about a data set.

What will that code look like ?

- `Proc CONTENTS`
- Data step or macro code that uses `VARNAME` function
- ... many other ways ...

In UNIX SAS can use stdio.

From "SAS(R) 9.2 Companion for UNIX Environments", [STDIO System Option: UNIX](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#unx-sysopt-stdio.htm)

> **Details**
>
> This option tells SAS to take its input from standard input (stdin),
>   to write its log to standard error (stderr), and to write its output
>   to standard output (stdout).
>   
>   This option is designed for running SAS
>   in batch mode or from a shell script. If you specify this option
>   interactively, SAS starts a line mode session.
>   
> The STDIO option
>   overrides the DMS, DMSEXP, and EXPLORER system options. The STDIO
>   option does not affect the assignment of the Stdio, Stdin, and Stderr
>   filerefs. See Filerefs Assigned by SAS in UNIX Environments for more
>   information.
>   
>   For example, in the following SAS command, the file
>   myinput is used as the source program, and files myoutput and mylog
>   are used for the procedure output and log respectively.
>   
>     `sas -stdio < myinput > myoutput 2> mylog` 
>   
>   If you are using the C shell, you should
>   use parentheses:
>   
>     `(sas -stdio < myinput > myoutput ) >& output_log`

With -stdio you want a short SAS program that can indicate if a variable is present in a data set, or perhaps emit a list of variables in a data set for further shell processing.  A `Proc CONTENTS` step is short and sweet.

So looking for your proverbial needle in a haystack

```
sasfile=<path to data set file>/<dataset>.sas7bdat
needle=GROUP
echo "Proc CONTENTS data=""$sasfile""" | sas -stdio | grep $needle
```

The default `CONTENTS` output might contain yield some false matches. So you could also try

```
echo "Proc CONTENTS noprint data=""$sasfile"" out=list;data _null_;set list;file print;put name;"
| sas -stdio
| grep -i "GROUP"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sasfile="sasdata"
rwords="GROUP"
grep -iw "$rwords" "$sasfile"
```

The only difference between these and your original commands is that I omitted `cat` and grep's quiet flag `-q`.

Sample input in `sasdata`:

```
fasd group                                                               
fdsfds fdsfdsa                                                           
fdsfd as GROUP afdsfdsa
```

Output:

```
fasd group
fdsfd as GROUP afdsfdsa
```

The `-q` flag of `grep` will suppress standard output but `echo $?` can retrieve the return value of `grep`. Using the same input file as before:

```
grep -iqw "$rwords" "$sasfile"   # No stout
echo $?                          # Prints 0, means grep succeeded
grep -iqw "word" "$sasfile"      # No stout
echo $?                          # Prints 1, means grep failed
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.I am using the same command which you suggested. It's working for rest variables but not working for 'GROUP' variable. I am not sure what is wrong with SAS dataset. I have double checked my command for variable name.